# Specify Makefile for C files in Xcode Objective-C project

Tags: c, xcode, makefile, compiler-errors

I have an `Objective-C` project in `Xcode`. I also have a bunch of `C` files that come with a `Makefile`. I want to integrate the `C` files into the `Xcode` project. Dragging the `C` files in the project does not work as `Xcode` complains of `undefined symbols` during compilation. How can I specify the `Makefile` so that `Xcode` can properly compile the `C` files?

Comment: Please, add more detail to your question, like: exact error you're getting, if the problem appears in the C files or in the Objective C ones, screenshots of the project's structure, C include path in your project settings, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating a static library in `Xcode` to compile the `C` files. I did not specify any `Makefile` there and the compilation was successful. I then referenced the library from the `Obj-C` project.